# Switch inside IEnumerator keeps looping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi folks I have this little 2D guy who has 2 states "IsSpeaking" and "Silence" I use them to make the Animator set a bool to true or false and the character seems to be speaking.

I need that the IsSpeaking lasts a different amount of time depending on the amount of text that is displayed on screen like this:

```
Text dialogueNumber(X) appears
Animate Speaking
Wait "X" time...
Animate Idle
Wait in Idle for next text (dialogueNumber) to appear and restart cycle...
```

I tried to do this with this little code:

```
void Update () {
 StartCoroutine(IsSpeaking());
}

IEnumerator IsSpeaking()
{
    switch (dialogueNumber)
    {
        case 0:

            yield return null;                              

            break;        

        case 1:

            functionsScript.IsSpeaking();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            functionsScript.Silence();                
            yield break;                

        case 2:

            functionsScript.IsSpeaking();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
            functionsScript.Silence();                
            yield break;
    }
    yield break;
```

So the longer the text the longer the Wait time to switch to the silence animation but it seems works fine the first time (case 1) and after it goes to silence it keeps going going back and forth randomly from IsSpeaking to Silence, I'm not sure if this was the best way to achieve this or if there's a better way to switch between states and wait an amount of time?

Thanks a lot for the advice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `IsSpeaking` every frame in the `Update` function which means it will be started over and over again even when the other one is not yet finished due to `WaitForSeconds`. Your current code could literately spawn over 400 coroutines running at- theme time and also trying to "speak" and "silence" at the-same time.

You can use a simple boolean variable to fix that issue.

```
bool speaking = false;

void Update()
{
    //Run only if not running
    if (!speaking)
        StartCoroutine(IsSpeaking());

}
```

Then set the boolean variable to `false` before breaking out of the switch statement in the coroutine.

```
IEnumerator IsSpeaking()
{
    speaking = true;

    switch (dialogueNumber)
    {
        case 0:

            yield return null;

            speaking = false;
            break;

        case 1:

            functionsScript.IsSpeaking();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            functionsScript.Silence();

            speaking = false;
            yield break;

        case 2:

            functionsScript.IsSpeaking();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
            functionsScript.Silence();

            speaking = false;
            yield break;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Comment: I did thought that it was looping because there was no exit instruction in update, now it's switching properly but after going to idle it returns immediately to speaking state I assume is looping this part of code:
            functionsScript.IsSpeaking();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
            functionsScript.Silence();

How do I keep it in Idle state Silence(); until next case?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are doing and what your current problem is. By looking at the mistake in your code, I suggest you understand basic Unity stuff before moving further. Do one of Unity's [project tutorial.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) That should get you started to start and finish your game.

Comment: @Programmer Doesnt this also start multiple coroutines or am i missing something?
As far as i understand it there should be a StopCoroutine, otherwise this will now just also switch the `speaking` back and forth.

Comment: @TheSkimek *"am i missing something?"* yes... `if (!speaking)
        StartCoroutine(IsSpeaking());` should prevent it from starting another coroutine until the old one has finished since `speaking` being set to `false` in the coroutine function before it breaks out of the coroutine.

Comment: Didnt realize `yield break;` will stop the coroutine. On second thought its obvious.

Comment: But it's not... Is not going to the next switch case but keeps looping the same coroutine, indeed I thought yield break should stop it but is not doing the trick do I really need to add stopcoroutine somewhere in the code? the character starts Idle speaks certain amount of time then goes briefly to Idle and then goes back to speaking the same certain amount of time and so on... never exits the same case but it does goes to the next one, any thoughts? @Programmer

Comment: but that's not what I'm asking really, I'm no expert but I'm not that kind of begginer, as @TheSkimek mentioned the yield break instruction should exit and maintain my character in Idle state or silence in this case, but instead it keeps looping, goes briefly to silence and goes back to speaking, any thoughts on this?

Comment: this is the question reformulated trying to be as specific as possible http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1413878/making-a-2d-character-speak-for-different-lenghts.html maybe is clearer this way?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt it be better to let the player decide when the next dialogue appears?
Not everyone reads the same speed.

Something along the line (hope thats not horribly on the wrong track):

```
while(!ExitDialogue)
{
    animation.Play("Idle");
    yield return StartCoroutine(IdleUntilNext()); //waits for player to press the defined button _keyCode_
    diaNumber++;
    animation.Stop("Idle");
    animation.Play("Speak");
    StartCoroutine(SpeakDialogue(diaNumber)); //wait for X seconds depending on diaNumber before stopping the animation
    animation.Stop("Speak");

}


IEnumerator SpeakDialogue(int diaNumber)
{
    switch (diaNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            yield break;
        case 2:
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(6);
            yield break;
        default:
            ExitDialogue = true;
            yield break;
    }


}

IEnumerator IdleUntilNext()
{
    while(!Input.GetKeyDown(_keyCode_))
    {
        yield return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No actually you got the idea, see my game has this dialogue manager and you switch to the next dialogue by pressing a button, I want that my character moves the lips more time or less time depending on the text dialogue that is currently displayed on screen, I assume that has to be checked in update to know which dialogue number I'm on and then pass that instruction to my character so he "knows" how many seconds he needs to move the lips but I can't get the enumerator to stop, I understand you can't set a coroutine in update but while (true) keeps freezing unity

Comment: here's the question reformulated http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1413878/making-a-2d-character-speak-for-different-lenghts.html maybe this will look much clear?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed my problem had a bad approach it was easier to make this outside the update function, turned out to be easier to set the number in the same "Next" button as a function called inside the On Click() resulting in something like this:

```
     public void TextID()
       {
         textID= (int)VD.nodeData.extraVars["cuadro"];
         print(textID);

             switch (textID)
             {
               case 0:
               break;

               case 1:
               StartCoroutine(LipsMoving(3));
               break;

               case 2:
               StartCoroutine(LipsMoving(6));
               break;
             }

        }

        IEnumerator LipsMoving(int talkTime)
         {
          funcionesScript.Speaking();
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(talkTime);
          funcionesScript.Idle();

          yield return null;
         }
```

In this way I get the frame ID as the user clicks the button and also runs my coroutine without weird loops.
Thanks again for the help and patience it's refreshing to have different points of view to find the right way, hope this is useful to you guys